# Which application is switching on wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3, logging

I am running Android 4.3 on a Samsung Galaxy S3, switching on or off WiFi on a need-to-use basis. A few days back, I realized that WiFi would spontaneously be switched on. I switched it off, but it would be switched on again.

I probably have downloaded an app or an update that is the reason for that behaviour. After trying to uninstall a number of these apps (no result up to now), I am wondering whether there is a possibility to log which app does what on the wifi connection, so as to identify the culprit.

I tried WIFi Fixer and saw a log line (among many others) that said:

> Failover set to: www.baidu.com

This makes me thinks the culprit tries to go to baidu (I have never connected to baidu). Avast scan does not detect a virus, so I am stuck.

Comment: This question might get closed soon due to the overly broad nature. Question: Can you remember what app install(s)/updates (might have) caused this?

Comment: Unfortunately, apps were updated semi-automatically (you know 20 of them are updated every week, e.g. google, maps, etc.). I eliminated a number of "suspects" by uninstalling them. So trace tool would be great.

Comment: More information: learning here and there, I installed Android Studio + sdk, and could use adblogcat to identify at least one app, namely "Mon réseau" by Orange (My Network, yes, I am French), which optimizes the 3g/4g/WiFi network to which it would connects. Even if you are not connected... so it enables the WiFi from time to time (but does not disable it).

Comment: Please leave this thread open until tomorrow same time in case I have an update.

Answer (score 1):

In china GCM (and many other Google services) are blocked by government. In order to send push notification to app in China there are multiple local service providers. One of them is Baidu, the link you are seeing in the logs.
Possible that some app is using that, instead of GCM.